# Odoo api.onchange & Boolean

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo-11

Odoo 10 - 
I have a Boolean field called floor. I would like to only run below if the Boolean is true. is this possible?

```
@api.onchange('suggestbox')
    def _onchange_squaremetrsold(self):
        self.squaremtrsold = (self.squarebox or 1) * (self.suggestbox)
        self.product_uom_qty = (self.squaremtrsold or 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
@api.onchange('suggestbox')
def _onchange_squaremetrsold(self):
    if self.floor:
        self.squaremtrsold = (self.squarebox or 1) * (self.suggestbox)
        self.product_uom_qty = (self.squaremtrsold or 1)
```

Comment: Thanks I was trying if self.floor==True. Your solution worked.